# URL Rewrites in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

With Nginx how would I rewrite

```
http://www.xxxx.com.au/forum/7-forums/
```

So it displays as

```
http://www.xxxx.com.au/forum/
```

I haven't had much experience with this and I am not even sure if it is possible so any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rewrite could be something like

```
rewrite /forum/7-forums/(.*) /forum/$1 last;
```

But then if I assume that `/forum` will always be handled by `/7-forums` I can use `alias` with `location`

```
location /forum {
    alias /forum/7-forums;
}
```